# Apache Beam : Java : write results to multiple files using a variable in TextIO.write()

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Need to write results to multiple output files and names of output files are generated at run time.

Example - Read from input csv that has students names and marks in each of the course. Output file has sum of marks for all the courses against student name.

Scenario 1 : Output results in a single csv - this is simple.

Input csv -

'''

ID,Name,Physics,Chemistry,Math,English,Biology,History

1001,James,56,60,78,67,50,70

1002,Robert,64,72,62,58,78,80

1003,Nina,72,70,83,72,75,85

Output csv -

```
    Name,Total
    Robert,414
    Nina,457
    James,381
```

Code snippet-

```
    pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFilePath()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new FilterHeaderFn(CSV_HEADER)))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ComputeTotalScoresFn()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ConvertToStringFn()))
                .apply(TextIO.write().to(options.getOutputFilePath())
                .withHeader("Name,Total").withNumShards(1));
```

Scenario 2: Output results in multiple files such that each student has a file created with their name and it contains total marks. Note - file names are generated at run time.
example -

```
Robert.csv => contains  414
Nina.csv => 457
James.csv => 381
```

I tried setting output file path inside
Code snippet -

```
`ProcessContext.getPipelineOptions().as(MyOptionClass.class).setOuputPath(output_path)`
```

but that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [dynamic file destination](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.29.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/DynamicFileDestinations.html) to achieve this, or a more generic [Runtime value provider](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.29.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/ValueProvider.RuntimeValueProvider.html)

Comment: Thanks, will try it out.